# Google+ Domains API: missing fields in activities.list method response?

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-plus-domains

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/activities/list), the `activities.list` method of the Google+ Domains API should return an `activity` resource containing an `access` field structured like this:

```
"access": {
  "kind": "plus#acl",
  "description": string,
  "domainRestricted": boolean,
  "items": [
    {
      "type": string,
      "id": string,
      "displayName": string
    }
  ]
}
```

However, in all the tests we performed only the `access.kind` and `access.description` fields are returned. So, for instance, we cannot retrieve the IDs of the circles the post is shared with.

Is there something we should specify in the request to enable the additional fields (like `items`), or it is simply a mismatch between the documentation and the implementation of the API?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a deficiency in the API and looks similar to [issue 398](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=398).